# Prove that $\operatorname{Gal}(K_1 / F_1)$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(K_2 / F_2) $ are isomorphic

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

> Let $K_1/F_1$ a field extension, and $\sigma : K_1 \rightarrow K_2$ a field isomorphism.
>
> If $F_2=\sigma(F_1)$, prove that $\operatorname{Gal}(K_1 / F_1)$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(K_2 / F_2)$ are isomorphic.

Intuitively, I see that for any $\phi \in\operatorname{Gal}(K_1/F_1)$, $\sigma \circ \phi \circ \sigma^{-1}$ is an automorphism that fix any $a\in F_2$, hence $\sigma \circ \phi \circ \sigma^{-1} \in\operatorname{Gal}(K_2 / F_2)$.

But I don't know if it is enough to prove the statement.

Comment: Yes the conjugaison by $\sigma$ is the isomorphism between the Galois groups, you have shown the injection then show the inverse

Comment: Yes it is, as conjugation is an automorphism of groups. Of course, *in this case* the conjugation occurs in a higer group that contains both Galois groups given in the question, but it is basically the same.

Comment: thanks for your comments